# Chrome change ui language crashes

Tags: google-chrome, language

Just installed chrome 4.0.245.0 on a brand new machine, and it insists I should use the localized ui. Whenever I try changing the ui language (Or even just open the language selector pop-up), it crashed on me.

Is there an easier way to change the language "from outside"? I saw there is a command line "--lang", but I couldn't get it to work. Anyone here knows the trick?

Comment: Consider upgrading to the latest one: http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/266.0/chrome_installer.exe

Comment: Yeah, the issue was solved since then by a simple upgrade. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up downgrading to the previous version, changing the ui language, and upgrading again.

used [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com) to get a previous version easily.